# Android App Indexing multiple actions

Tags: android

Here is the tutorial I am following.

http://regularmotion.kr/android-app-indexing-introduction/

I have a question regarding adding actions to the AppIndexAPI. Is it possible to do add multiple different titles to the appindexapi. So far the following will add mTitle to the appindexapi but what if I also want to add mtitle2, mtitle3 etc...

```
Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, mTitle, uri);
AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mClient, viewAction);
```

Comment: Do you have the answer now? Does it work?

Comment: All I did is created an arraylist of actions and started each one everytime I run the activity.

Comment: When I tried it only the last action worked